# I have what I believe is probably a very simple HTML related issue

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email, signature

I have been trying to get my work signature to look identical on my Android to the one I have in Outlook.

I have almost succeeded in this, the only difference between the two at this point is that there is an empty line between each sentence - there should be no space.

I have been trying to tinker with this for quite a while, but I am not nearly familiar enough with coding to figure out what the problem is.

All I'm looking for is for this code to be edited such that there is no gap between each sentence, or even for someone to merely point out what it is I need to remove from the code and I can then go about continuing to tinker.

I would really appreciate all the assistance I can get.

This is the code:

```
<html>
<body lang="EN-CA" link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72" style='tab-interval: 36.0pt'>
    <div class="WordSection1">
        <p class="MsoNormal">
            <o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
        </p>
        <p class="MsoNormal">
            <o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
        </p>
        <p class="MsoNormal">
            <a name="_MailAutoSig"><b><i><span style='font-size: 14.0pt; mso-ascii-font-family: Calibri;
                mso-fareast-font-family: Calibri; mso-hansi-font-family: Calibri; mso-bidi-font-family: "Times New Roman";
                color: #002060; mso-fareast-language: EN-CA; mso-no-proof: yes'>Hassan Mahmood</span></i></b></a><span
                    style='mso-bookmark: _MailAutoSig'><span lang="EN-US" style='mso-ascii-font-family: Calibri;
                        mso-fareast-font-family: Calibri; mso-hansi-font-family: Calibri; mso-bidi-font-family: "Times New Roman";
                        mso-ansi-language: EN-US; mso-fareast-language: EN-CA; mso-no-proof: yes'><o:p></o:p></span></span></p>
        <p class="MsoNormal">
            <span style='mso-bookmark: _MailAutoSig'><span lang="EN-US" style='font-size: 10.0pt;
                mso-ascii-font-family: Calibri; mso-fareast-font-family: Calibri; mso-hansi-font-family: Calibri;
                mso-bidi-font-family: "Times New Roman"; color: #002060; mso-ansi-language: EN-US;
                mso-fareast-language: EN-CA; mso-no-proof: yes'>Direct Tel.: 416-214-2277<o:p></o:p></span></span></p>
        <p class="MsoNormal">
            <span style='mso-bookmark: _MailAutoSig'><span lang="EN-US" style='font-size: 10.0pt;
                mso-ascii-font-family: Calibri; mso-fareast-font-family: Calibri; mso-hansi-font-family: Calibri;
                mso-bidi-font-family: "Times New Roman"; color: #002060; mso-ansi-language: EN-US;
                mso-fareast-language: EN-CA; mso-no-proof: yes'>Fax: 647-497-5724<o:p></o:p></span></span></p>
        <p class="MsoNormal">
            <span style='mso-bookmark: _MailAutoSig'></span><a href="mailto:hmahmood@chippingham.com">
                <span style='mso-bookmark: _MailAutoSig'><span style='font-size: 10.0pt; mso-ascii-font-family: Calibri;
                    mso-fareast-font-family: Calibri; mso-hansi-font-family: Calibri; mso-bidi-font-family: "Times New Roman";
                    mso-fareast-language: EN-CA; mso-no-proof: yes'>hmahmood@chippingham.com</span></span><span
                        style='mso-bookmark: _MailAutoSig'></span></a><span style='mso-bookmark: _MailAutoSig'><span
                            lang="EN-US" style='font-size: 10.0pt; mso-ascii-font-family: Calibri; mso-fareast-font-family: Calibri;
                            mso-hansi-font-family: Calibri; mso-bidi-font-family: "Times New Roman"; color: #002060;
                            mso-ansi-language: EN-US; mso-fareast-language: EN-CA; mso-no-proof: yes'><o:p></o:p></span></span></p>
        <p class="MsoNormal">
            <span style='mso-bookmark: _MailAutoSig'></span><a href="http://www.chippingham.com/">
                <span style='mso-bookmark: _MailAutoSig'><span lang="FR-CA" style='font-size: 10.0pt;
                    mso-ascii-font-family: Calibri; mso-fareast-font-family: Calibri; mso-hansi-font-family: Calibri;
                    mso-bidi-font-family: "Times New Roman"; color: blue; mso-ansi-language: FR-CA;
                    mso-fareast-language: EN-CA; mso-no-proof: yes'>www.chippingham.com</span></span><span
                        style='mso-bookmark: _MailAutoSig'></span></a><span style='mso-bookmark: _MailAutoSig'><span
                            lang="FR-CA" style='font-size: 10.0pt; mso-ascii-font-family: Calibri; mso-fareast-font-family: Calibri;
                            mso-hansi-font-family: Calibri; mso-bidi-font-family: "Times New Roman"; color: #1F497D;
                            mso-ansi-language: FR-CA; mso-fareast-language: EN-CA; mso-no-proof: yes'><br>
                        </span></span><span style='mso-bookmark: _MailAutoSig'><span lang="EN-US" style='font-size: 7.5pt;
                            font-family: "Arial","sans-serif"; mso-fareast-font-family: Calibri; color: #1F497D;
                            mso-ansi-language: EN-US; mso-fareast-language: EN-CA; mso-no-proof: yes'>
                            <br>
                        </span></span><span style='mso-bookmark: _MailAutoSig'><b style='mso-bidi-font-weight: normal'>
                            <span style='font-size: 14.0pt; font-family: "Cambria","serif"; mso-fareast-font-family: Calibri;
                                mso-bidi-font-family: "Times New Roman"; color: black; mso-fareast-language: EN-CA;
                                mso-no-proof: yes'>
                                <img border="0" width="350" height="74" id="Picture_x0020_1" src="http://www.chippingham.com/image001.jpg"
                                    alt="CFG_Crest 74x350"></span></b></span><span style='mso-bookmark: _MailAutoSig'><span
                                        lang="EN-US" style='mso-ascii-font-family: Calibri; mso-fareast-font-family: Calibri;
                                        mso-hansi-font-family: Calibri; mso-bidi-font-family: "Times New Roman"; mso-ansi-language: EN-US;
                                        mso-fareast-language: EN-CA; mso-no-proof: yes'><o:p></o:p></span></span></p>
        <p class="MsoNormal">
            <span style='mso-bookmark: _MailAutoSig'><span lang="EN-US" style='font-size: 10.0pt;
                mso-ascii-font-family: Calibri; mso-fareast-font-family: Calibri; mso-hansi-font-family: Calibri;
                mso-bidi-font-family: "Times New Roman"; color: #002060; mso-ansi-language: EN-US;
                mso-fareast-language: EN-CA; mso-no-proof: yes'>Suite 2105 &#8211; 77 King Street
                West, Toronto-Dominion Centre PO Box 357, Toronto, ON M5K 1K7</span></span><span
                    style='mso-bookmark: _MailAutoSig'><span lang="EN-US" style='mso-ascii-font-family: Calibri;
                        mso-fareast-font-family: Calibri; mso-hansi-font-family: Calibri; mso-bidi-font-family: "Times New Roman";
                        mso-ansi-language: EN-US; mso-fareast-language: EN-CA; mso-no-proof: yes'><o:p></o:p></span></span></p>
        <p class="MsoNormal">
            <span style='mso-bookmark: _MailAutoSig'><span lang="EN-US" style='mso-ascii-font-family: Calibri;
                mso-fareast-font-family: Calibri; mso-hansi-font-family: Calibri; mso-bidi-font-family: "Times New Roman";
                mso-ansi-language: EN-US; mso-fareast-language: EN-CA; mso-no-proof: yes'>
                <o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
            </span></span>
        </p>
        <span style='mso-bookmark: _MailAutoSig'></span>
        <p class="MsoNormal">
            <o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much in advance for your assistance; it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I see that an edit has been made to break it down into three sentences instead of one, but I imagine that was for clarity more so than fixing the code? Again, please feel free to correct me if I am wrong; I'm not in any way being negative or criticizing, I'm just wanting to clarify whether or not that edit will solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML you post seemed to be produced from MSOffice (via Outlook, I guess), which means *no human will ever willing read it*.

My suggestion is to just toss it out, and write it from scratch using simple HTML.

```
 <div>
      <div style="font-weight:bold;font-style: italic;">Hassan Mahmood</div>
      <div>Direct Tel.: 416-214-2277</div>
      <div>Fax: 647-497-5724</div>
      <div>
          <a href="mailto:hmahmood@chippingham.com">hmahmood@chippingham.com</a>
      </div>
      <div><a href="http://www.chippingham.com">www.chippingham.com</a></div>
      <div>Suite 2105 – 77 King Street West, 
            Toronto-Dominion Centre PO Box 357, Toronto, ON M5K 1K7
     </div>
</div>
```

From there, you can added `style=` attributes to adjust it the way you like.

Comment: I understand that Outlook tends to be generically Microsoft esque by nature and thus difficult to work with, however my dilemma is that I need the signature to mimic the office conventions.

If I had the ability to dictate the overall policy, I would edit the signatures across the company for simplicity's sake, however, I am not in the position to do that.

It took quite a while to even get to the point that I pasted compared with the code that I had gotten off Outlook; the only thing that is different between the mobile signature and the Outlook signature are the breaks between lines.

Comment: Office-generate HTML isn't "Microsoft esque" -- it's overly arcane and confusing, mostly because it needs to be "round-trippable" --- It needs to be able to regenerate the original DOC file by reading the HTML file.  Because of this, about 95% of the generate Html is unnecessary when displaying it as Html.  From the simplified Html I've given you, you can add `style` attributes on any of the `DIVs` to mimic the original.

Comment: Would I be able to rip off the style attributes from the code I provided originally? Or would I need to do some research as to how best to add the style attributes I need? My dilemma is there are various fonts and colours.

Thanks a lot!

Really sorry if I'm being a pain.

Comment: If you want to dig through all that to pick details out, have at it! The important details seem to be: Calibri font, 14 point for the first line, 10 point for the rest.